# Getting max/min value from list of rasters in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

I have 3 Rasters and would like to have the max/min value from all of these raster using ModelBuilder.

[image: Model]

Unfortunately the "Get Raster properties" tool gives me the value of each Raster separately.

Comment: You could run a cell statistics with the maximum of three rasters before getting raster properties:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/

Comment: And if I use 365 rasters, how can I get the Max value from all of that? For example the max yearly temperature from all rasters(one raster for each day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm), it doesn't matter if you have 3 or 365 rasters, you can put a list of as many as you want (theoretically). And if your machine cannot handle it because your extents are too big or you have very high resolution, you can always use model builder or a python script to iterate it.

[image]